# view in HeaderInSection size not increasing

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview

I have try to give title for section in uitabelview, The label contaning view size is not able to increase more than 50, Here my code,

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
if(tableView.tag==20)
{
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, 55)];
    [view addSubview:label];
    [view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:166/255.0 green:177/255.0 blue:186/255.0 alpha:1.0]]; 
    return view;
}
}
```

How to add section like as in the image,

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will resolve your issue.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
 return 100;
}
```

Enjoy the coding......

Answer (score 1):

Go to xib in Table set in setction Height see the below image [image]